# what is the difference between [g] and [ɣ]?

Tags: phonology

Does [ɣ] appear in english anywhere? I've seen [ɣ] listed as occuring in the spanish word "amigo" but I don't notice any difference between it & [g]. The Arabic equivalent is [غ].

Comment: Do you speak either of Spanish or Arabic, or just using them as an example?

Comment: See their position in the [IPA chart](https://www.ipachart.com/) (and listen to the recordings). Their place of articulation is the same (velar), but [g] is a plosive and [ɣ] is a fricative.

Comment: Most Spanish speakers will swear up and down that the g sound in _un gato_ and the one in _mi gato_ are the same, which of course they aren’t. They’re unconscious allophones of the same morpheme in Spanish, and even in isolation they find them difficult to distinguish.

Comment: Arabic [غ] is similar but not equivalent (unless we're talking about some dialect where the phonetics has changed) – that consonant is uvular, IPA [ʁ]. Compare intervocalic /g/ in Spanish or Tigrinya, which are velar [γ].

Comment: I don't speak Arabic, but I took Spanish in school & it never to occured to me that _un gato_ & _mi gato_ where different sounds either. The 'n' in 'un' can almost sound like a 'ŋ', but I've never considered those different sounds. Spanish is also better than english about having enough letters to match the number of sounds (although 'g' can still be 'h' or 'g'). 'l' & 'll' are both seperate letters.

Comment: Wiktionary seems to imply that غ & ɣ are the same sound. The latter is used to describe the former's sound in MSA.

Answer (score 4):

For the first question: no, it does not appear in English. As for the second part, [g], as a plosive consonant, is made by interrupting the airflow by pressing your tongue against the soft palate (velum), whereas [ɣ] is almost the same thing but the air can pass through a small space between the tongue and the velum, it is what we call a fricative consonant.